# How can I install klogd on ubuntu trusty?

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I am trying to find how can I install the kernel daemon logger on ubuntu trusty (14.04.2). It looks like it does not run on my machine after `ps aux |grep klogd` .  `locate` does not find it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found my own answer: `klogd` works with `syslogd`. Ubuntu uses `rsyslogd` which does not not need the klogd server at all. In fact, `rsyslogd` reads the `/proc/kmsg` file itself. So everything works as is with the default configuration from Ubuntu.

Trying to install the `busybox-syslogd` on my ubuntu machine broke its configuration: any nic interface was no longer showing up in `ifconfig` or `ip link show`, event after full reboots... I suggest to not install this package, unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

To install [klogd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/busybox-syslogd) in 14.04, run the following commands:

> `sudo apt-get install busybox-syslogd`